¿Cuál es el origen de "doblar las campanas" para un muerto?
Cuando yo era niño, aprendí una canción (en una iglesia evangélica) que comenzaba con:

Las campanas suenan tristes, como muestra de dolor...

En este uso, las campanas suenan por la muerte de una persona.
Pero en una traducción de For Whom The Bell Tolls (Hemingway), el artículo de wikipedia lo da como Por quién doblan las campanas. Según entiendo, la voz inglesa toll significa "hacer sonar la[s] campana[s] anunciando la muerte de alguien". Entonces, una expansión de la traducción sería "Por quién suenan la campana anunciando su muerte" o "Por quíen tocan la campana anunciando su muerte"
Aparentemente no está relacionado con Toll del inglés.
Toll en inglés viene del

Old English *tollian, preserved in betyllan "to lure, decoy," and fortyllan "draw away, seduce," a word or element of obscure origin. Etymonline/toll

Etymonline no da certeza del origen de la palabra inglesa, pero no muestra conección al Latín; y no supe encontrar otra evidencia de que sean cognados toll con doble.
Recursos Españoles
En el Diccionario de Autoridades - Tomo III (1732), aparece que

Significa tambien tocar las campanas a muerto echándolas a vuelo. Latín. Aere campano lessum facere: feralem cantum enunciare. HORTENS. Paneg. pl. 193. "Iban a doblar por él, detuvo los Religiosos el varon justo." NIEREMB. Var. ilustr. Vid. del P. Marciel de Lorenzana, §. 7. "Luego que se supo su dichoso tránsito, doblaron las campanas en todas las Parróchias y Conventos." RAE.es

Y encontré esta entrada informativa en un blog, indicando que el doble es el nombre de este toque de las campanas:

Para anunciar un óbito, las campanas tocan a muerto o doblan. Es muy frecuente el empleo de la expresión doblar a muerto, pero resulta redundante. Ese toque es el doble (Dejó escrito que a su muerte se dieran seis dobles en la torre). Otros nombres del anuncio de muerte mediante toques de campana son clamor y posa. En León y algunas provincias de Castilla, de la campana que toca a muerto se dice que encuerda. lavozdegalicia.es

Siendo así, sería un tanto repetitivo decir "doblar la campana por el muerto". Debería decirse mejor "doblar al muerto".
¿Por qué este toque se llama doblar?
¿Tiene algo que ver con el doble del L. Duplus?

CAMPANAS EN LA NOCHEEEE, RUIDOS DE MELANCOLÍAA QUE ESPERAN... QUE ESPERAAAN... ESPERAN QUE ELLA VUELVA Y ME DIGA: ACÁ ESTOY, MI AMOR, NO EXISTE EL OLVIDOOOOO, ACÁ ESTOY, MI AMOR, DE VUELTAAAAAAAAAA

Según Fundéu, "doblar" hace alusión a un tocar solemne, diferente del repicar, que es alegre:

Doblar y repicar, referidos al tocar de una campana, son verbos con matices opuestos en su significado.


En algunos medios de comunicación es frecuente la confusión de estos dos términos: «Cuando finalmente haya fumata blanca doblarán las campanas de la Basílica de San Pedro» o «El pueblo se enlutó, al saber de su muerte repicaron las campanas de la iglesia».


Según recoge el Diccionario de la lengua española, doblar, dicho de las campanas o de otros instrumentos, significa ‘tocar a muerto’; por el contrario, repicar implica ‘tañer con cierto compás en señal de fiesta o regocijo’.


Por lo tanto, en los ejemplos anteriores habría sido preferible escribir «Cuando finalmente haya fumata blanca repicarán las campanas de la Basílica de San Pedro» y «El pueblo se enlutó, al saber de su muerte doblaron las campanas de la iglesia».

En respuesta a tu comentario:

Siendo así, sería un tanto repetitivo decir "doblar la campana por el muerto". Debería decirse mejor "doblar al muerto".

"doblar al muerto" parece un ejercicio de tanatopraxia (doblar al muerto para que entre en el ataúd). Es necesario indicar el instrumento.

Entonces? Cuál es el origen de la acepción de ‘doblar’ (o doble) para referirse a tocar las campanas?

Es un significado registrado por el diccionario: las campanas doblan, los tambores redoblan

Ajaja eso seguro que sí, máster. El punto es qué paso antes de que fuese a parar al diccionario.

Puedo aventurar que se deba al efecto del sonido. Lo mío es la semántica, no la etimología.

Apostaría a que tiene que ver con el ritmo del tañido, tratándose el doble de un compás en dos y el redoble en cuatro, con lo que estaríamos ante uno de los ritmos más lentos que se pueden aplicar a un instrumento de percusión.

@Bardo Algo así es lo que busco, pero el DRAE y el DECEL no dan informacióni al respecto.
